# How to pass Javascript dictionary to controller where C# dictionary value is an object

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Imagine this Javascript dictionary:

```
var things = {};
things['1'] = 10;
things['2'] = 11;
```

Here's a little bit of ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Controller/Foo',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        things: things
    },
```

Here's something that works:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo(Dictionary<string, int> things)
```

things will show that 1 maps to 10 and 2 maps to 11.

Here's something that DOES NOT work:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Foo(Dictionary<string, object> things)
```

things will show that 1 maps to null and 2 maps to null.

I can not change the Dictionary types.  In reality, that Dictionary is part of a complex object that is used throughout the application (on the C# side of things).  What you are looking at is a dumbed-down example.

In addition, JSON.stringify does not help at all.  In fact, if I stringify the dictionary I get a count of 0, with no values.

Using C# to express my point, I think the expectation is more this (than what is currently happening):

```
int x = 5;
object foo = (object)x;
```

The dictionary was defined like this because one could be doing:

```
things[key] = 1;
```

or

```
things[key] = "string";
```

that's why it was declared as an object.

I am using ASP.NET Core if that matters (and jquery 3.4.1).

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could custom a `DictionaryModelBinder` like below :

```
 public class DictionaryModelBinder:IModelBinder
{
    public  Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

        var result = new Dictionary<string, object> {};
        var form = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;
        if (form==null)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError("FormData", "The data is null");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
        foreach ( var k in form.Keys){
            StringValues v = string.Empty;
            var flag = form.TryGetValue(k, out v);
            if (flag)
            { 
                result.Add(k, v );
            }
        }

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(result);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Foo([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(DictionaryModelBinder))]Dictionary<string, object> things)
    {
        // the stuff you want
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can bind to `object` as a parameter (or `Dictionary` value type) because:

> A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind. When model binding occurs, the class is instantiated using the public default constructor.

I think you could either strongly type your `object` (which sounds like it's not an option for you) or change your endpoint to take all its relevant properties distinctly as simple types (`string`, `bool`, `int`, etc.).

Reference: [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding#complex-types)